# Internet becomes abeyant gradually on phone usage

Tags: notifications, internet

Observed this problem in the following devices:

1. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 GT-P3100. - Android JB.
2. Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2 GT-S7582. - Android JB.
3. Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro Sk17i. - Android ICS.

When the phone is new or, fresh factory reset, the mobile Internet connectivity is really active. This means, messages in WhatsApp, email notifications from GMail occurs properly in time. But gradually on usage, say 2 - 3 months, these apps take more time to notify new messages when the screen is off. When the screen is ON, messages are received instantly.

1. Observed only in mobile Internet. (H+ or H - WCDMA auto mode).
2. Not observed when in Wi-Fi.
3. Facebook notifications are in-time and this problem is not observed by the app. Only WhatsApp and GMail tend to suffer.

What could be the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are all the devices on the same carrier? That could well be the common factor here.

Comment: No, different carriers. And the first two HSPA+ and the third one EDGE.